# What's the performance penalty in calling Object.setProtoytypeOf() in the following code?

Tags: javascript, prototype, javascript-engine

I have been [hearing quite a lot that `Object.setPrototypeOf()` in JavaScript is not a good thing to do](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/The_performance_hazards_of_prototype_mutation). It reduces optimizations and lowers down the performance of an application.

Specifically, it reduces some inline caches and fast prototype property lookups made for a given object.

Now, I have one question in my mind that doesn't seem to have been answered anywhere online. That is:

If `Object.setPrototypeOf()` removes inline caches and wastes other optimizations, then this would only be applicable, and rigorously true, when it's called multiple times while an application is running. For e.g. if I have an object `o` and I, let's say, change its `[[Prototype]]` on click of a button, then this would be the *bad thing*.

However, I don't see *any issue* whatsoever, in doing the following thing:

```
function Parent() {
    this.a = 1;
}

Parent.prototype.helloParent = function() {
    console.log('Parent.');
}

function Child() {
    this.b = 2;
}

Child.prototype.helloChild = function() {
    console.log('Child.');
}

Object.setPrototypeOf(Child.prototype, Parent.prototype);
```

Two constructor functions `Child()` and `Parent()` are created, and then `Parent.prototype` is set as the prototype of `Child.prototype`. This prototype mutation via `Object.setPrototypeOf()` is done immediately before any other code is run, so perhaps once the first property lookups on `Child` instances are performed, the JS engine could optimize their property accesses.

I couldn't understand exactly **what might be the performance issue** with this code specifically, assuming that `Object.setPrototypeOf()` is called in the application ***only* in this way**.

Comment: _"I have been hearing quite a lot that Object.setPrototypeOf() in JavaScript is not a good thing to do. It reduces optimizations and lowers down the performance of an application."_ - If you add such assumptions/statements in your question then please also add an example (+ a link to the source) for those.

Comment: [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/setPrototypeOf) has a warning box as the first ting in their docs. They suggest creating a new object instead of changing the prototype.

Comment: Yes, I know about that. But that doesn't answer my question.